# Getting expression too complex error .please correct me if i have done thing wrong

Tags: swift

```
let b0 = UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 0 + (0 << 2)]) << 0 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 1 + (0 << 2)]) << 8 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 2 + (0 << 2)]) << 16
        b0 = b0 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 3 + (0 << 2)]) << 24
    let  b1 = UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 0 + (1 << 2)]) << 0 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 1 + (1 << 2)]) << 8 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 2 + (1 << 2)]) << 16
        b1 = b1 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 3 + (1 << 2)]) << 24
    let b2 = UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 0 + (2 << 2)]) << 0 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 1 + (2 << 2)]) << 8 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 2 + (2 << 2)]) << 16
        b2 = b2 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 3 + (2 << 2)]) << 24
    let b3 = UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 0 + (3 << 2)]) << 0 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 1 + (3 << 2)]) << 8 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 2 + (3 << 2)]) << 16
        b3 = b3 | UInt32(block[block.startIndex + 3 + (3 << 2)]) << 24
```

Comment: There's a clear pattern here. You could simplify the code using loops, arrays and maybe functions as well.

Comment: You code contains patters like  `let b0 = <expression> b0 = b0 | <expression>`. I.e. you define `b0` as a `let` constant and try to update the value afterwards?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, `b0`..`b3` are `let` constants, but you're reassigning to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just format this code properly, you'll see there's a very clear pattern:

```
let start = block.startIndex

let b0 = UInt32(block[start + 0 + (0 << 2)]) << 0
       | UInt32(block[start + 1 + (0 << 2)]) << 8
       | UInt32(block[start + 2 + (0 << 2)]) << 16
       | UInt32(block[start + 3 + (0 << 2)]) << 24

let  b1 = UInt32(block[start + 0 + (1 << 2)]) << 0
        | UInt32(block[start + 1 + (1 << 2)]) << 8
        | UInt32(block[start + 2 + (1 << 2)]) << 16
        | UInt32(block[start + 3 + (1 << 2)]) << 24

let b2 = UInt32(block[start + 0 + (2 << 2)]) << 0
       | UInt32(block[start + 1 + (2 << 2)]) << 8
       | UInt32(block[start + 2 + (2 << 2)]) << 16
       | UInt32(block[start + 3 + (2 << 2)]) << 24

let b3 = UInt32(block[start + 0 + (3 << 2)]) << 0
       | UInt32(block[start + 1 + (3 << 2)]) << 8
       | UInt32(block[start + 2 + (3 << 2)]) << 16
       | UInt32(block[start + 3 + (3 << 2)]) << 24
```

Each `b` constant is just the numbers `0...3` transformed in similar ways, all bitwise-OR'ed together. Sounds like a job for `map`/`reduce`:

```
let start = block.startIndex
let b0 = (0...3).lazy.map{ UInt32(block[start + $0 + (0 << $0)]) << $0 * 8 }.reduce(0, |)
let b1 = (0...3).lazy.map{ UInt32(block[start + $0 + (1 << $0)]) << $0 * 8 }.reduce(0, |)
let b2 = (0...3).lazy.map{ UInt32(block[start + $0 + (2 << $0)]) << $0 * 8 }.reduce(0, |)
let b3 = (0...3).lazy.map{ UInt32(block[start + $0 + (3 << $0)]) << $0 * 8 }.reduce(0, |)
```

This can be even further simplified, if you made a `b` array with 4 elements, rather than 4 seperate `b#` variables:

```
let start = block.startIndex
let b = (0...3).map{ x -> UInt32 in
    fatalError("I don't know what the number x represents, so I just named it x. Give it a better name.")
    return (0...3).lazy
                  .map{ UInt32(block[start + $0 + (x << $0)]) << $0*8 }
                  .reduce(0, |)
}
```